# Code Excerpt: Does this create a vulnerability to XSS?

Tags: javascript, css, security, xss

So I'm relatively new to JavaScript, although I've been doing HTML/CSS UI frontend work forever (blasphemy, I know) and am in the process of developing my own boilerplates for use with future projects. I'm also fairly new to the idea of securing code from XSS, CodeInjection etc.

The following is a fully working excerpt that I've been working on. In production, the JavaScript will be minified and loaded from an external file, not loaded inline, it's just for the example for ease of use.

I'm wondering if by creating variable output as plain text and inserting it via document.getElementById("x").href, leaves an opening to vulnerabilities such as CSS attacks. There is a ton of information regarding these types of vulnerabilities, but as a relative newcomer to the secure code environment, it's daunting and a bit overwhelming.

PS, the `<p></p>` is also just for testing.

Thanks to all in advance!

For the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Title</title>

        <!-- required CSS -->

        <!-- conditional CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/mq/null" id="mediaquery" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <p id="test"></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function setCSS() {
            if (window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 767px)").matches) {
                layout = "mobile";
            } else if (window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)").matches) {
                layout = "tablet";
            } else if (window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px)").matches) {
                layout = "desktop";
            } else if (window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 1281px)").matches) {
                layout = "xldesktop";
            }
                window.addEventListener('resize', setCSS, false);
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = layout;
                document.getElementById("mediaquery").href = 'assets/css/mq/device.'+layout+'.css';
        })();
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: NB: you'll be creating an ever increasing set of event listeners bound on `resize` with this code.

Comment: You really should do this with a CSS-only mediaquery.

Comment: I was worried about that, however in testing and using the developer tools within Chrome, I'm not seeing an increase in HTTP requests whenever the window size is changed.

Is there a more thorough way to be sure?

Comment: What kind of XSS vulnerability are you thinking about? The question is always: **Where** does the "*variable output*" come from?

Comment: @Bergi the whole reason for doing this is to restrict overhead, designing for mobile first, it makes no sense for mobile users to download assets meant for large desktop environments, etc.  I've read articles regarding the negligent hit on performance by including all assets in a single CSS file, or simply loading all external CSS files, however I feel this is cleaner. Assets are loaded on demand.

Comment: @Bergi I had come across this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_CSS_Injection_(OTG-CLIENT-005)

Comment: @GabrialMacLeod if your reply is to me, chances are you'll only see an HTTP request if the media changes.  However the code as written will _definitely_ cause an ever increasing set of calls to `setCSS` for each resize event that will progressively slow down the browser.

Comment: I don't think a `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 1281px)" href="assets/css/mq/device.xldesktop.css">` would be loaded by a mobile device?

Comment: @GabrialMacLeod: So what? If the attacker can't control the `layout` variable (and how would he?), he can't load arbitrary css.

Comment: @Bergi that was my suspicion, thank you for confirming

Comment: @Alnitak I guess you're correct, in that a user could potentially sit there and continually resize their window back and forth incessantly, or do the same thing regarding portrait/landscape orientation of their device which is kind of silly. However is there a better method to use than the "resize" trigger? I'm still writing down notes for things to research and follow up on

Comment: @Alnitak he could probably use namespaces together with jQuery and unbind the resizer and poke a new one: `jQuery.bind('resize.glob', ...` and `jQuery.unbind('.glob');`

Comment: @AxelAmthor no, it would be simplest just to create an outer IIFE (to avoid global scope polution) and then make sure that the call to `addEventListener` is _outside_ of `setCSS`.

Comment: @Alnitak Right, if it is that simple. But where is "outside" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only part of your posted code that could lead to an XSS vulnerability is

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = layout;
```

If you are setting `innerHTML` and you have any HTML in your layout variable that could be user controlled then this could be an attack vector. However, in this case `layout` appears to be one of either `mobile`, `tablet`, `desktop` or `xldesktop`.

If you want to include any user set content or content from an untrusted source, you should [HTML encode your output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124052/413180). In this case I would not go with the accepted answer as it does not appear to include the single or double quote characters which as essential for XSS prevention, but the answer by Anentropic will make your output secure for output in an HTML context.

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

The quote characters are required to be encoded because if you output to a quoted attribute value then a malicious user could escape this context otherwise. Please note if you output to unquoted attribute values then you must [escape all characters with ASCII values less than 256 except for alphanumeric characters](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes).

Another route is to use JQuery where you can set the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) property rather than [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).